# How to align spaces in CMD code output

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

My Batch code:

```
@echo off
set phones="iPhone 12" "Galaxy S5 4G" "Nokia 7"
set manufs=US "South Korea" Finland
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=& for %%a in (%phones%) do set /a n+=1& set phone[!n!]=%%~a
set n=& for %%a in (%manufs%) do set /a n+=1& set manuf[!n!]=%%~a
for /L %%a in (1 1 %n%) do echo !phone[%%a]! : !manuf[%%a]!
pause
```

Output:

```
iPhone 12 : US
Galaxy S5 4G : South Korea
Nokia 7 : Finland
```

How to align space/ tab before : so it becomes:

```
iPhone 12    : US
Galaxy S5 4G : South Korea
Nokia 7      : Finland
```

> **Update 1** <<30/03/2024>>

I found this method and work properly.

```
@echo off
set HPs="iPhone 12" "Galaxy S5 4G" "Nokia 7"
set CTs=US "South Korea" Finland
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=& for %%a in (%HPs%) do set /a n+=1& set HP[!n!]=%%~a
set n=& for %%a in (%CTs%) do set /a n+=1& set CT[!n!]=%%~a
set n=& for %%a in (%HPs%) do (
    set /a n+=1& set $HP=%%~a
    for /L %%i in (0 1 12) do if "!$HP:~%%i,1!" NEQ "" set Len=%%i
    set Len[!n!]=!Len!& set Lens=!Lens! !Len!
)
for %%a in (!Lens!) do (if not defined max Set max=%%a
if %%a GTR !max! Set max=%%a)
set "space= "& for /L %%a in (1 1 !max!) do set Spaces=!Spaces!!space!

rem Finally
CLS& for /L %%V in (1 1 %n%
) do call echo !HP[%%V]! %%Spaces:~!Len[%%V]!%%: !CT[%%V]!
pause
```

Output:

```
iPhone 12    : US
Galaxy S5 4G : South Korea
Nokia 7      : Finland
```

Maybe someone can write code simpler and faster

Comment: Windows batch file do not have a string-length or pad function, but you can use a *pad* function, such as this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398545/string-processing-in-windows-batch-files-how-to-pad-value-with-leading-zeros, to fill the first string with spaces to a fixed length. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398545/string-processing-in-windows-batch-files-how-to-pad-value-with-leading-zeros