# Get Highest Value from String Batch File

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

Batch code:

```
set list=4 8 1
for %%a in (%list%) do set highest=???
```

how can I get and save the highest value into a variable?

Comment: I am only going to give you some hints of what to learn.  If I were to make this happen, I would use `CALL :<label>` with your list.. as in `call :MyFunction %list%`.  In that function, I would use the SHIFT function to make my way through the list.  Start with learning how the [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) (label version) works coupled with a `goto :EOF` statement and how passed parameters show up as %1 %2 %3 etc for both the batch itself and the functions you call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following batch code will find the highest integer :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set list=4 8 1
set max=
for %%a in (%list%) do (
    if not defined max (Set max=%%a)
    if %%a GTR !max! (Set max=%%a)
)
echo max is %max%
```

Comment: Thanks. I use this code to automatically get max length for this: https://superuser.com/questions/1837054/how-to-align-spaces-in-cmd-code-output