# Get some spaces in a Batch

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

In PowerShell:

```
$val = ' '
$val *=5
write-host "[$val]"
# Output is 5 spaces:> [     ]
```

But in Batch:

```
set "val= "
set /a val*=5
echo [%val%]
rem Output is zero:> [0]
```

How i can get 5 spaces from one space (variable) in Batch like in Powershell above?

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. set val=' ' echo %val% What are you trying to do?

Comment: get some spaces from one space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also possible in batch, but the code is much less elegant
than in bash.

Here is an example :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "char= "
set number=5
set result=
for /l %%a in (1,1,%number%) do  (set "result=!result!!char!")
echo result="!result!"
```

Comment: Thank You. This is what I mean

Comment: I use this code to automatically get some spaces for this:  https://superuser.com/questions/1837054/how-to-align-spaces-in-cmd-code-output